# Bootstrap strange space between spans

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with a row to show a product list, with a span9 as a container and each product has a span3 size which gives 3 in each row.

But i am watching a strange phenomenon, some spans are not showing 3 per line.

Like this:([see full size image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeFi3.png))
[image]

The bootstrap version is 2.3.2 and i am using the responsive capabilities.

Hope someone can help.
Thanks

Comment: It appears that your `<div class="*span*">` tag has a `margin-left: 20px`...

Comment: Yep, but that margin don't resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using the module (%3) of your index to add rows around your spans.
So your function would be something like this:

```
while($products as $key => $product) {
    //Put product info here
    if($key%3 = 2){
        echo "</row><row>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, actually i used your idea and it was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to override the `class*="span"` selector.

[image]

```
div [class*="span"] {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Tried that, but is not the solution. I have used a php solution unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your image, the problem appears to actually be floats not clearing. Notice that the grey long sleeved shirt (col 1, row 2) has four lines of description while everything else has 3. 
With Bootstrap, you need to wrap every set of spans with div class="row".
An alternative workaround could be to apply a clear:left; to every fourth span.
Something like this:

```
.product-container .span3:nth-child(4n+4) { clear: left; }
```